# Is it possible to re-map FO4's enforced/unmappable keys?

Tags: fallout-4

*Update: Fallout version 3.1—in beta as of this writing—resolves this problem (hallelujah). If you're still experiencing this problem, and if 1.3 is still in beta, you can install the beta via Steam by following [these instructions](http://steamcommunity.com/games/377160/announcements/detail/903336711828944209).*

While in Workshop mode, pressing the "F" key will rotate the object you're trying to build and place. The key for this action isn't mappable through the in-game UI.

That works fine with the default key mapping. But I always remap my movement keys to ASDF, so in Workshop mode I can't move forward. I've been site-stepping and backing up to get around town.

This is just one example of a possible conflict with unmappable keys. The "E" key [seems to be a source](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fallout/comments/3s9nx2/does_anyone_know_how_to_change_the_key_mapping_in/) of [problems too](http://steamcommunity.com/app/377160/discussions/0/496880503081236570/).

Is it possible to remap keys if their mappings aren't exposed through the UI? On the PC there's an intriguingly named file at

```
G:\Documents\My Games\Fallout4\ControlMap_Custom.txt
```

but its contents are pretty inscrutable. And there were a couple of [Skyrim mods](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/1380/?) for [remapping keys](http://www.nexusmods.com/skyrim/mods/88/?), but it's early for the FO4 community to have one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [AutoHotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to [remap keys](http://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Remap.htm#Remap). Obviously this isn't an ideal solution since you have to install something and remember to turn the script on and off, but it should work until a mod comes up.

Comment: Would that work in this situation though? The problem isn't that I want to remap "F" to a different key. It's that most of the time Fallout 4 respects my key mapping ("F means forward"), but some of the time it doesn't ("F means rotate item"). If AutoHotkey would just let me remap Forward to a different key, I can do that through the in-game UI. I need something contextual: while in Workshop mode, map Fallout 4's rotate *function* to a different key, while preserving my "F means forward" mapping.

Comment: @FeralChimp You can bind the movement action to, say the J key, and then swap the F and J keys using AHK. When you press F Fallout receives a J (bound to movement), when you press J Fallout receives an F (hard-bound to rotate)

Comment: Slick. So I'm taking advantage of the fact that FO4 doesn't have a predefined use (mappable or otherwise) for the "J" key. Works great.

Comment: Note that AHK scripts can be made to detect specific applications as explained [here](http://superuser.com/a/88239/151383) by using IfWinActive.

Answer (score 0):

can't see how this would work. 
Fo4 hard-codes workshop menu navigation to the cursor keys for example.
These can be mapped through the UI to Movement...but of course the moment that you open the Workshop you can no longer move. (apparently the hard code takes priority and movement ceases.)

There is an F4se dependent mod available called Keymapping done proper. it works really nicely but for the fact that once in a while Steam will force an update that breaks F4se and you need to wait a couple of days for the guys that support it to catch up and release an update of their own.

At present it seems that there is no method of inhibiting the Dictatorware that is Steam from auto-updating. (apart from keeping your pc offline at all times.)